# CoreData - Invalid number of rows using fetched controller

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I know this is a common error, but I don't understand why it's happening here. In the first vc, when an add button is pressed, the user is segued to a second vc to create a new record. In the second vc everything goes along fine until I try to save the context. At that point, the first vc tries to insert the new record and the app crashes without saving.

Second VC:

```
private func createNewRecord() {
   let newRecord = Record(context: context)
   newRecord.recordNumber = "xxxx"
   currentCustomer?.addToRecords(newRecord)
   coreData?.saveContext() //App tries to insert new record on first VC here and crashes
   fetchCurrentRecord()
}
```

First VC:

```
func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
   switch type {
   case .insert:
      if let insertIndexPath = newIndexPath {
         recordTableView.insertRows(at: [insertIndexPath], with: .fade) //CRASH!!
      }
etc.
```

tableView methods (first VC):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return recordFetchedController.fetchedObjects?.count ?? 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! RecordCell
   let record = recordFetchedController.fetchedObjects![indexPath.row] as Record
   cell.recordNumber.text = record.recordNumber
   return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   performSegue(withIdentifier: "EditRecordSegue", sender: self)
   tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   if editingStyle == .delete {
      let record = recordFetchedController.fetchedObjects![indexPath.row] as Record
   context.delete(record)
   coreData?.saveContext()
   }
}
```

FetchedResultsController:

```
func configureFetchedController(searchString: String) {
   let customerFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Record>(entityName: "Record")

   let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "customer.name CONTAINS[c] %@", searchString)
   customerFetchRequest.predicate = predicate

   let firstSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "dateModified", ascending: false)
   customerFetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [firstSortDescriptor]

   recordFetchedController = NSFetchedResultsController<Record>(
   fetchRequest: customerFetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)  

   recordFetchedController.delegate = self
}
```

And here is the error: The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out). with userInfo (null)

Comment: What is `fetchCurrentRecord()` about? And do you use an extra data source array in First VC ?

Comment: It assigns the newly created record to a variable that gets passed along as needed. I didn't need to include it in my example as it never gets called. And no - I only use a fetched results controller.

Comment: Please can you show the code for your tableView datasource methods (particularly `numberOfRowsInSection`: it is returning `1` when it should return `2`).

Comment: That's the strange thing - I erased the app and started over...the error above is coming from the first attempt to add a record.

Comment: Intriguing.  How is the FRC set up?

Comment: I just added the FRC code - nothing fancy.

Comment: Is Customer to Record set to `to-many`?

Comment: Yes - Customer has a to-many relationship to Record called records.

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be completely unrelated to my fetched controller code. There is a separate customer table that sends a notification when a new customer is selected. The second VC responds to this notification by going back to the first VC. Which was good. But later I decided the customer table should move the currently selected customer to the top when a new record was being added. This had the unintended consequence of sending another notification which resulted in the second VC starting to create a new record but then getting dismissed immediately. And crash. It makes me think that I need to learn more about testing.

Answer (score 1):

## One cause of this horrible problem!

In short, I happened to have a **base class** for the table view I had forgotten about. As it happened, it had an overload for `reloadData` ...

```
override func reloadData() {
    super.reloadData()
    
    if isLoading {
        emptee.removeFromSuperview()
        return
    }
    
    if dataSource?.tableView(self, numberOfRowsInSection: 0) == 0 {
        addSubview(emptee)
    }
    else {
        emptee.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

As you can see, it just relates to an "empty message"

## In the code, it does call for `numberOfRowsInSection` ...

Unfortunately, I had the call like this:

```
override func reloadData() {
    // my code ...
    super.reloadData()
}
```

rather than like this!

```
override func reloadData() {
    super.reloadData()
    // my code ...
}
```

That was the entire problem.